# Percentage points abbreviation

Tags: abbreviations, percentages

I am writing an academic essay (APA standard) in which I compare a lot of proportions (and probability estimations).

Phrases like

> ... are 5.2 percentage points more likely to ...

are common. So I want to use an abbreviation. But not sure if to use *pps*, *PPs*, *pp*, *PPt*, or just pp. Curiously, I find nothing from APA or anyone else when doing a quick web search looking for best practices. At this point any insights or standard I can follow is good enough.

**Update**

Percentage point is different from a percent (literally part of a hundred).

*Example*:

> 30 percent of customers complained about our service last year. This year
>   only 24 percent.

So we would say there has been 6 percentage points decrease in complaint but the decrease is also 0.06/0.30 = 0.2 = 20 percent.

Comment: What's wrong with just "points"?

Comment: Not bad but still ambiguous perhaps.

Comment: Not if you're discussing polls, or something else that uses percentage points.

Comment: The rate of complaint is down 6%.

Comment: @HotLicks That's a common misunderstanding. http://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-points.html

Comment: I suspect that you're the one that misunderstands.  30 percent and 24 percent are rates of complaint.  The two rates differ by 6 percent.

Comment: Trust me on this one. Also here is another link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point

Comment: Did you notice that I said "**rate**"????

Comment: I see it now at least and I would still argue that the correct language is "The rate of complaint is down by 20 percent".

Comment: The very fact that you are having to go to considerable pains to demonstrate to Hot Licks that "5.2 percentage points" differs fundamentally from "5.2 percent" is to me a strong indication that you shouldn't make the distinction even more difficult to grasp—which I think would happen if you shortened "5.2 percentage points" to anything else. My advice: Spell out "5.2 percentage points" in full, and promise yourself that you'll make up the difference by tightening up loose wording or removing superfluous content elsewhere in the text.

Comment: @rhetorician I think you are wrong but I neither have time nor do I think this is the appropriate place for dicussing that. I was just asking for an abbreviation not asking for correction of my understanding of technical terms in my field of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest choosing any of these abbreviations, like *pp*, and clearly defining this for your readers at the beginning. I think using the abbreviation would actually make it less likely for someone to misinterpret what you are describing, since it is much more natural for people to assume we are discussing *percent change* (as evidenced by the initial interpretations of your question).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point) indicates that *pp* is used, but the reference provided seems to not directly support this. Other [references](http://acronymsandslang.com/definition/947304/PPT-meaning.html) indicate *ppt* may be used.

I would lean towards *pp* only because when I see *ppt* I think of "powerpoint" and this may be distracting for readers.

> ... are 5.2 pp more likely to ...

---

As a somewhat of an aside, this is definitely a less usual way of describing differences in proportions, so do be cautious about your phrasing. See [this link](https://www.reed.edu/academic_support/pdfs/qskills/percent.pdf) for some examples of phrasing you might be able to use, which might even help clarify your point to your readers.

> "...percentage of uninsured Americans rose by 9 percentage points."

Comment: +1 agree on ppt <-> Powerpoint . On the side note: "more likely to" makes sense if you are talking about change in probability.

Comment: I think you actually are correct in your phrasing. I think it just is a less common way of expressing the change. I will edit my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

How about **percent** or **%**?

Each of the following is common parlance:

> ... are 5.2 percent more likely to ...
>
> ... are 5.2% more likely to ...

There is no abbreviation that I am aware of of the sort you've mentioned, and personally I see no need for one.

Addendum: I answered the question that was originally asked. Based on the update to the question, it is now obvious that the OP is seeking an abbreviation for *percentage points* as per the example in the update. So, for example, if 30% changed to 24% for some reason, that change would correspond to a decrease of 6 *percentage points*. The question is this: Is there a best-practice (broadly-accepted?) abbreviation for *percentage points*? Personally, I am not aware of one, but any author could adopt an abbreviation, such as *pp* or *ppt* or  *ppts* or %pts, provided they define it so the reader can understand it. Maybe some other user will have a more satisfying answer.

Addendum: See my comment below on the difference between using *decrease* and *difference*. In my first addendum, I should have used "difference of 6%" rather than "decrease of 6 percentage points". Had I used *difference*, there would have been no need to talk about *percentage points* at all. In fact, one often sees the term *percent difference* or *% difference*, either of which can be positive, negative, or zero.

Comment: Not the same. See update to original post

Comment: @snoram Thanks for the comment. Your update was not there when I responded, and if it was, it appeared while I was composing my response. It changes the question. Actually, given your example, I would be tempted to go with the 20% decrease and not worry about percentage point differences. Everything is relative.

Comment: Yes. My update was sparked by your answer. Sorry for the confusion. But I suggest you delete or update your answer.

Comment: @snoram It's okay. No harm done. I think it's better to leave it as is. The comments will, I hope, make it clearer to other users what you are seeking.

Comment: What do you mean? The answer is just misleading!

Comment: @snoram I added an addendum. I hope it helps.

Comment: @snoram One more thought. The problem may relate to the difference between *decrease*, which you used, and *difference*. If 30% of something changed to 24% of something, you could characterize that as either a *decrease* of 20% (which I would tend to do, although *decrease* is somewhat ambiguous) or as a *difference* of 6%. If you were to use *differences*, you wouldn't have to worry about *percentage points* or abbreviations. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is problematic, as it is certainly not a valid answer to OP's redefined question. Since 'percentage points' was present from the start, the correct procedure before clarification would have been to close-vote on grounds of lack of clarity. 'There is no abbreviation that I am aware of of the sort you've mentioned, and personally I see no need for one....Maybe some other user will have a more satisfying answer.' certainly should not be receiving upvotes (and gstats provides abbreviations that have been used).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Edwin, I appreciate your comment. I was unsure of the proper procedure for revising my answer based on the OP's update. As I said, I had answered the original question as I understood it. I then added an addendum to try to clarify matters. What should I have done, and how would I have moved to close-vote? Finally, gstats provided his/her answer after I provided mine.

Comment: I've found it rather difficult tracing the edit history, but I think a close-vote is probably warranted at all times. Even if 'How about _percent_ or _%_?' was at one time the correct answer, it should hardly be what we are coming up with on ELU. I've voted to close the present edition on lack-of-research grounds; gstats found _pp_ in Wikipedia (though his tenacity in going on to find _ppt_ is praiseworthy). It's the usual judgement call between close-voting inadequate questions (why 2 upvotes!?) vs appreciating the beyond-the-basics research some contributors put in in answering.

Comment: This isn't correct. "percentage point" is not the same as "percent". You seem to be debating the validity or definition of the term "percentage point", which is a well established concept: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point). The notion that the words "difference" or "decrease" have any effect on what is proper to say is also incorrect.